# how to check gps status in phonegap?

Tags: cordova, gps

I want check whether GPS enabled or disabled in phonegap.

and display an alert when the GPS status changed

I have done this in android.

Answer (score 1):

From the phonegap [docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_geolocation_geolocation.md.html)

```
var watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(geolocationSuccess,
                                              [geolocationError],
                                              [geolocationOptions]);
```

You might want to do something like this(untested)

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
    alert(position.coords.latitude) //or logitude and etc
});
```

and if you want to stop watching

```
geolocation.clearWatch
```

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444279/i-am-getting-lat-long-coordinates-in-phonegap-geolocation-without-using-intern) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518468/phonegap-gps-without-internet), could be helpful.